# jquery, How to add HTML hex icon class with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add style with jquery, the style contains ascii icons
css classes:

```
.plusIcon:before {
content: "\2b";}
.minusIcon:before {
content: "\2212";}
```

When I loading the style from stylesheet it works fine:
plus icon content is "\2b" (display "+" on html page) and the minus icon content is "\2212" (display "-" on html page)

[image]

[image]

, but when I am loading the css style with jquery the content changes

jquery code:

```
var css = '.minusIcon:before {content: "\2212";}.plusIcon:before {content: "\2b";}'
jQuery('head').append('<style>' + css + '</style>')
```

The  tag added to my html page but the classes content changed to:
plus icon content is "2b" (display "2b" on html page) and the minus icon content is "2" (display "2" on html page)

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to add this style with jquery in a  way that those icons with be shown?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try escaping the character like `content: "\\2212"` for each occurrence of  single back slash. i.e. replace single back slash  with double back slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at below changes. You need to escape the single back slash with double back slash whenever you are dealing them via JS string:

```js
var css = '.minusIcon:before {content: "\\2212";}.plusIcon:before {content: "\\2b";}'
jQuery('head').append('<style>' + css + '</style>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="minusIcon"></span>
</br>
<span class="plusIcon"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/7hsj8xcm/)

You can do that using Jquery's **addClass()** function. Its very easy to use as,

(Include Jquery first)

**Your HTML**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

**Your CSS**

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    background:#FFF}

.plusIcon:before {
    content: "\2b";
    font-size:30px;}

.minusIcon:before {
    content: "\2212"; 
    font-size:30px;}
```

**Your Jquery**

```
$("#div1").addClass("plusIcon");
$("#div2").addClass("minusIcon");
```